# How to dynmically load path in tsconfig.json file?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I would like to use dynamic import in my playwright scripts to load a certain data file depending on the environment parameter.
Something like this:

```
let data: Promise<username: string, password: string>;
data = import("@test-data/user_data.json");

test("my env test", async => {
   (await data).username;
})
```

I think `@test-data/user_data.json` should be defined in the `tsconfig.json` file like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "strict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@test-data/*": [
                "stage/users/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can dynamically specify here the `stage` in the path `stage/users/*` based on my environment (which I could read from the process.env variable specified while running the test)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. The only thing I think it could work is setting a placeholder into the dynamic field and create a specific bash/node/wathever script that fill the field according to the environment or an inline variable.

Could be nice put it as [postinstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) script into the package.json to run it each time you install the dependencies.